# Transistors absolute maximum values

Tags: voltage, transistors, maximum-ratings

[image] 
[image]
As you can see this a transitor AND gate and yet the LED glows when only one input is high,  passing the current essentially through the base and emitter. I think I fried (I think) my transistor since I'm running the transistor at the absolute maximum (this is a 2n2222a and that is a 7806 voltage regulator) bar voltage.

I need to know the effect of exceeding the each absolute maximum and whether these are salvageable.

Also,  what happens in the transistor when you exceed absolute maximum values (in the NPN junction, in terms of holes and electrons and why the damage is permanent)

[[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: "As you can see" No, we can't see. You didn't post a schematic and the photo is poor: it is impossible to see the connections of the parts on your breadboard, nor how they are powered (only the red wire from the positive terminal of the battery is shown, where does the negative go?)

Comment: If you overheat the semiconductor too much then the electrons fall into the holes and can't get out.

Comment: @Lorenzo Donati better picture added.

Comment: We still can't see how the components are connected. Use the built-in schematic editor (control-M) and add a diagram to your question.

Comment: @Dave Tweed , Alright , schematics added

Comment: VCBO collector-base voltage open emitter − 75 V
VCEO collector-emitter voltage open base − 40 V
VEBO emitter-base voltage open collector − 6 V
IC collector current (DC) − 600 mA
ICM peak collector current − 800 mA
IBM peak base current − 200 mA
Ptot total power dissipation Tamb ≤ 25 °C − 500 mW
Tstg storage temperature −65 +150 °C
Tj junction temperature − 150 °C
Tamb ambient temperature −65 +150 °C                     Those are the stated max values on the data sheet, which one of this max values do you think you are running at or exceeding?? because I do not think you are exceeding any

Comment: @SpehroPefhany No it's really the other way around! ;-) If you overheat the semiconductor electrons begin to jump out of holes (maybe because it's too hot there :-D )

Comment: Your schematic only shows one transistor - where's the AND gate?

Comment: Clearly, the schematic does not match the breadboard. Where's the 7806 regulator, the 9V battery, the second transistor? And with the one-transistor circuit you've drawn, why do you think the LED should NOT be lit?

Comment: OK, I think I might see the problem. Are any of the resistor legs touching any of the metal transistor cases? If so, the transistor will turn on even if the other leg of the resistor is open.

Comment: @Dave Tweed,  .  I'm so sorry in my haste I messed I,  I fixed it now.  I think the current has to flow through the collector to the emitter but it's passing through the base to the emitter.  I tried again with a fresh transistors and this happened again (is it because the base emitter if forward biased?) This is not very helpful for logic gate since the output from the emitter becomes the next base but yet transistor logic gates are made. Isthere any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know the effect of exceeding the each absolute maximum and
>   whether these are salvageable.

Exceeding absolute maximum ratings is always bad, that's why they are called *absolute*. And almost every datasheet I've ever seen states something like this:

[image]

The amount of damage can vary from a negligible (for your application) degradation of the performance of the device to a complete fireworks show. Of course it's intuitive that the largest the overstress and the longer it is applied the worse are the consequences.

Anyway, once you go beyond the maximum ratings, even for the tiniest amount and for the smallest time interval, you cannot trust the datasheet any longer. This doesn't mean it is sure 100% your device has been damaged, but it may well be. You could be lucky and have a part which is, due to manufacturing spread, more capable than the average of its kind, but there is no way to know. That is, for small over-stresses such a "stronger specimen" could survive with no damage whatsoever, but to be sure it really wasn't damaged you'd have to fully characterize the device again, i.e. you should repeat the same procedure the manufacturer does when he collects the data to compile the datasheet.

Of course, at hobbyist level such procedure is almost infeasible, so you are left with simple testing, such as checking whether the junctions of a BJT still behave as diodes using a multimeter with diode-checking capability. Even if you have a multimeter with a BJT tester this will be almost useless, since it would measure the actual hFE under some unknown conditions, and that will tell you nothing about whether the performance was better before the overstress "accident".

You could do some simple functional test, i.e. plug the BJT into some simple circuit that you know it's not critical, i.e. it doesn't rely on tight part specifications (such as using the BJT to switch on a LED), and see if it works. That will tell you that the BJT is still "usable", for some foggy definition of *usable*, of course.

> Also, what happens in the transistor when you exceed absolute maximum
>   values (in the NPN junction, in terms of holes and electrons and why
>   the damage is permanent)

The exact process that brings a device to be damaged is a very broad area: you may want to google for "BJT failure modes" and see what pops up.

And "why the damage is permanent": why do you expect a physical object not to have limits? If I load a nylon rope too much it breaks. Neglecting *how exactly the rupturing process evolves*, would you expect a rope to be indestructible? The same is for electronic devices. The maximum ratings are just that: the limits beyond which the device is likely to break.

Comment: Switched to 5 volts,  no fireworks in my house thank you.  I just tried connecting an LED to the emitter and connecting the be to positive while leaving the collector hanging ; the led glowed. Since the emitter is output having even a small current can turn transistor logic gates on.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh - Please, go find somebody who can explain transistors to you. Your concepts are so out of touch with reality that I don't know if anybody here can help you.